# fb like button not shown in webview loading local html

Tags: android, facebook, webview

I use mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/test.html") but the like button does not shown. And the logcat show fb:like failed to resize in 120s. How can I resolve it?

test.html

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>(function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.3&appId=xxxxxxxxxx";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
    <div class="fb-like" data-href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="false"></div>
```